# Does not render component

Tags: angularjs, stackblitz

I have created AngularJS simple project using stackblitz, i am unable to
add module name.

i have tried multiple times, as a new bee bit confused.

here is a link for my project error.
https://angularjs-nbhgkj.stackblitz.io
full project
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-nbhgkj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with the following line.

```
window.app = angular.module('app','date', requires);
```

change it to

```
window.app = angular.module('app', requires);
```

because angular.module expects module name and dependency array.

Comment: yes it works, but in date folder i have "hello world", how to render date component ?thats i am confused. updated link :https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-nbhgkj?file=app.js    and https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-nbhgkj?file=date%2Fdate.html @Allabakash

Comment: you are using date as a directive , for that you need to create a directive. checkout this updated code. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-xpekvq?file=date%2Findex.js.

Comment: welcome @John Walter :) i hope it answered your query. Click on Checkmark in left, if it is cleared.

Comment: yeah, last one problem i am having,i am adding date picker but only texts are rendering, date picker is not rendering...https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-ycomem?file=home%2Findex.js

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-ycomem?file=date%2Fdate.html @Allabhaksh

Comment: That is not working as you have not imported angular-material lib to your app. Please go through this. https://material.angularjs.org/latest/getting-started

Comment: @John Walter  Here is updated code. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-u6uojn

Comment: Thanks for help in all way mate! Happy Coding:) @Allabakash